# How do I make Django template HTML file load CSS/JS without putting Django code in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have an `index.html` in my `templates` folder. In the HTML file's `head` tag is `<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>`.

When I open a terminal in `templates/` and run `python manage.py runserver`, the HTML loads just fine. But I get a 404 error like this: `GET /PATH/TO/scripts/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2446`

`index.html` can't find my JS file. Without editing `index.html`, how do I make the HTML file load the JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `static` and `{% load static from staticfiles %}`,

like this:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'scripts/main.js' %}"></script>
```

---

> NOTE: This is NOT suggested in Deploy/Production service.

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [ ... ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) # static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # media file
```

You have to set `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` in your `settings.py` before add those to `urls.py`.

> NOTE: This works with `DEBUG=False` in `settings.py`

You have to run `runserver --insecure` to let django serve static files.

So you can add with this:

```
<script src="/static/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

> /static/ may be replaced with your `STATIC_URL`

Comment: Yes, in your `index.html`. put `{% load static from staticfiles %}` on your 1st line of HTML, and put `<script src="{% static 'scripts/main.js' %}"></script>` in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: How do I accomplish what I need without having to edit 'index.html'?

Comment: You want not using Django Template Engine? then you should set `DEBUG=False` and set `STATIC_ROOT` to your static directory, and set django url to serve static files manually. OR you can set NginX or Apache2 to serve your static files when approach to `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: I really suggest you to use `static` method in your Django Template.

Comment: How do I set Django URL to serve static files manually? How do set NginX or Apache2 to serve static files in the way you described? Why would I need to use the `static` method?

Comment: your question is too large to explain in comment. Search with `django static serve`, and if you can't find solution, then try new question.

Comment: My original question was how to make the template load static files without editing the template. If you edit your answer to show how to do that, I can mark your answer correct

Comment: Answer update: But this is not the way with django. Unless using Front-end framework like React or Angular, you'd better to use Django Template for your web service.